# Remove all HTTP bindings from an IIS 6 site while leaving SSL bindings

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, iis, bindings

We have a (remote, via a reseller) customer who configured their IIS6 server to not have any port 80 HTTP bindings, only port 443 SSL bindings.  We would like to reproduce this without going through the three layers (!) to get to the customer to test some error scenerios.

However, whenever I try to get IIS to not listen on IIS at all, I can't do it.  If I do it in the UI, either leaving in the main properties page, or in the advanced bindings page, the UI does not let me proceed.  If I remove the HTTP ServerBindings from the metabase.xml directly, IIS makes it port 80, all unassigned addresses anyway.

Is there a way to get to the "SSL only" state naturally?  Please note I am NOT talking about the "require SSL" checkbox or underlying metabase setting, as that still listens on port 80 (or whatever) to give the "SSL required" error message.  I'm talking about not having any bindings listed at all for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Would blocking port 80 at the firewall achieve the desired result?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no.  The issue is not access to port 80.  We have an installation script that fails when it enumerates the ServerBindings properties if there are no such bindings present.  We are trying to reproduce that scenario.